# Select branch on Xcode 6 bot

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode6

In Xcode [Server] 5.x when creating a bot we were able to specify [which branch to check out for the remote when building](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots/ConfigureBots.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH9-SW2).  How could you achieve the same results in Xcode 6?  The options don't seem to be available within Xcode when creating the bot, or from the browser when viewing it on the web.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a some investigation it appears the only obvious way to select a different branch for a bot is to have that branch checked out at the time the bot is created.  This can be done from within Xcode:

`Source Control > [your project name] > Switch to Branch`

After which you can create your bot which will check out this branch when integrating.

I really don't like this behaviour and have to assume there's a workaround for this

Comment: I agree. The way of selecting a branch regardless of your current branch was much better.

Comment: Also it appears that a new build is kicked off regardless of which branch has been committed to, which feels wasteful. Has anyone else noticed this behaviour?

Comment: Didn't see that one yet, we haven't done too many builds with this new server.  Xc6 seems a little dumbed down from a build perspective IMO

Comment: I guess the bots in XCode 6 are dependent on the schema we are currently using. If the schema is on a different branch, thats what the bot will do. Maybe we can edit that somehow?

Comment: @JoãoNunes it shouldn't make a difference which branch the scheme is on? (my shared schemes are on a number of different branches afaik)

Comment: @GeorgeSealy I can confirm your finding that a commit to a branch kicks off bots that are set to poll for commit changes. I'd hope (and expect) that Apple will bring back branch control. Failing that, clearly specify that bots live on the branch they're created on in the docs somewhere.

Comment: I'm seeing that the Bot is only run when commits are made to a specific branch, which I see selected under the `Source Control` menu . Is there a way to make sure that the integration is run when a commit is made to *any* branch?

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 7 you can now select the branch.

In Xcode 5 and 6 you can add the following to a "Before Integration" script.

`git checkout NameOfYourBranch`

Comment: Good call - and it's a better answer than mine IMO.  Both still feel a bit hacky/clunky though.

Comment: Saved me with this! thank you so much for this simple workaround.

Comment: If you do that you need to launch the integration manually, the "on commit" can't work